# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre .Value y . Value 2?

Tags: vba

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "Target.Value" y el "Target.Value2"?, ¿Cuándo se debe ocupar cada uno?

Comment: Deberías de poner un ejemplo de a lo que te refieres. ://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Value` devuelve el valor de la celda, con el formato que haya aplicado Excel por defecto.
`.Value2` devuelve el valor puro de la celda, sin ningún formato. Es decir, te devolverá siempre un valor numérico o de texto (o nulo)

Ejemplo: Escribe en `A1` una fecha, por ejemplo, 04/09/2020. Luego, ejecuta esto:

```
Debug.Print Range("A1").Value, Range("A1").Value2
```

En la ventana inmediato, obtendrás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A efectos de cálculo, ambos casos son un número, pero `.Value` te lo muestra formateado como fecha, y `.Value2` te lo muestra como número.

En resumen, `.value2` te devuelve el valor numérico, ignorando formatos como Fecha o Moneda.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pude entender de mejor manera con tu ejemplo. Pd: Sabes donde puedo estudiar los códigos de mejor manera?

Comment: Si por códigos te refieres a aprender VBA como tal, no te puedo recomendar ninguna fuente, porque hay tantas que son muy buenas, que no sabría decirte.